missing TCP traffic using wireshark, on a wifi external usb adapter in monitor mode
I am using an ESP32-C6 running a small http server, connected with an OpenWRT AP without security (open , but I had same result when using WPA2, thereby capturing the handshake).  2.4 GHz only.
I've set up an Alfa AWUS036NHA wifi adapter in monitor mode on raspberry pi 4 running Kali Linux 2024.3 (kernel 5.15.44, aircrack-ng RTL8814AU driver), to sniff on the channel (11). I can see all UDP traffic, but no TCP traffic. I see the DHCP address being assigned, but that is about the only direct messages I see towards the ESP32.
When I execute a request towards the webserver with postman (GET) from another computer in the network then I see a correct answer coming (also on the wireshark logging on this computer that executes the GET), but I don't see this communication being logged by wireshark on the device that captures the wifi traffic . It seems that those packets are somehow missed by the wifi adapter.
With airmon-ng check kill, I made sure that no other software messed with the channel.
I also did the same from an Kali VM running on MacOS, but same result.
I also tried with an alfa adapter AWUS1900.
Does anybody have an idea what what I am missing?

Make sure you've enabled Promiscuous mode instead of/in addition to Monitor mode.  If that's working, then it's usually something in the stack of adapter/driver/OS is ignoring those packets, which can be difficult to do much about. You should read their wlan capture wiki page here: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

I thought I could ignore the promiscuous part as monitor mode is a superset of promiscuous mode.  As seems to be confirmed here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80500/promiscuous-vs-monitor-mode-in-802-11.
Anyway, I tried to add the flag with ifconfig wlan1 promisc, and then the flag is shown. But I still see a lot of dropped frames, of which I assume those are the ones I am missing in the log.
